# Scraping webpage when filter does not change URL

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to scrape http://csla.history.ox.ac.uk/search.php after applying a filter as follows

1. clicking on 'Saint'
2. selecting 'Gaul and Frankish kingdoms' under 'Region of Birth/Burial'
3. clicking on 'Apply Search'

I struggle as the URL does not get updated accordingly.

The source code with the `<option value="Gaul">Gaul and Frankish kingdoms</option>`looks as follows

```
<div class="section colm colm6" id="fl-page4-12">
<label for="item_12"class="field-label">Region of Birth/Burial</label>
<label class="field select">
<select id="text-nine" name="form[item_89]">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="East">'The East' (unspecified)</option>
<option value="West">'The West' (unspecified)</option>
<option value="Britain">Britain and Ireland</option>
<option value="Gaul">Gaul and Frankish kingdoms</option>
```

From the selected webpage, I then would like to access the IDs that are written in blue, i.e. the first one  would be `E06478`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky one. You need to `POST` the query to the server, and the query needs to be in a very particular format. You can get the html from the page like this:

```r
library(httr)
library(rvest)

items <- c(998, 1, 18,89, 90, 2, 88, 20, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 13, 11, 999, 213, 214)
contents <- c('\nE\n', '\n\n', '\n\n', '\nGaul\n', rep('\n\n', 11), '\nOr\n',
              '\n\n', '\n\n')
s <- paste0("-----------------------------39565121210000504382566389445\n",
       "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"form[item_", items,
       ']\"\n', contents,
       collapse = '')
s <- paste0(s, '-----------------------------39565121210000504382566389445--')

type <- paste0('multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------',
               '39565121210000504382566389445')

res <- POST('http://csla.history.ox.ac.uk/results.php',
           body = charToRaw(s),
           content_type(type))
```

To get all the results in a neat data frame, you can then do:

```r
df <- res %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_elements(xpath = "//td[not(contains(@style, 'LightGray'))]") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  matrix(ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  setNames(c('ID', 'Title')) %>% 
  dplyr::as_tibble()
```

This gets you all the reference IDs in a data frame. To get the actual pages, we use these as query strings:

```r
urls <- paste0("http://csla.history.ox.ac.uk/record.php?recid=", df$ID)
```

Now we need to go through all 900+ pages to extract the tabular data. It's safest to do this in a loop then bind the list together at the end:

```
all_results <- list()

for(i in seq_along(urls)) {
  all_results[[i]] <- read_html(urls[i]) %>% 
                       html_elements("td") %>% 
                       html_text() %>%
                       matrix(ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE) %>%
                       as.data.frame() %>%
                       setNames(c("ID", "Name", "Name_in_source", "Identity"))
}

final_result <- dplyr::bind_rows(all_results)
```

The final result is now a data frame with over 3000 rows. Here are the first 3:

```
head(final_result, 3)
#>       ID                                       Name Name_in_source Identity
#> 1 S01319          Orientius, bishop of Auch, 5th c.                 Certain
#> 2 S02351 Mamertus, bishop of Vienne (Gaul), ob. 475                 Certain
#> 3 S00316                            Martyrs of Lyon                 Certain
```

Some of the IDs are duplicates since they appear in multiple pages. You could use `unique` to remove these. Note also that when you are printing a data frame to the console, Greek letters will appear as Unicode escape sequences. The text is still there in the underlying vector though. For example:

```r
head(final_result[3])
#>                                                       Name_in_source
#> 1                                                                   
#> 2                                                                   
#> 3                                                                   
#> 4                                                                   
#> 5 <U+03A0><U+03BF><U+03BB><U+03CD><U+03BA>a<U+03C1>p<U+03BF><U+03C2>
#> 6           <U+03A0><U+03B9><U+03CC><U+03BD><U+03B9><U+03BF><U+03C2>
```

But

```r
final_result[1:6, 3]
#> [1] ""          ""          ""          ""          "Πολύκαρπος" "Πιόνιος"
```

Comment: Thank you, Allan! That helps me a lot already!

Instead of scraping ID and Title, I want to click on the blue-marked IDs (e.g. for E06478, it would be http://csla.history.ox.ac.uk/record.php?recid=E06478) and scrap from those "ID", "Name", "Name of Source" and "Identity" (which are listed in the table called "Related Saint Records"). 

Do you have another advice for this?

Comment: @natalieee OK - that required scraping over 900 pages to ensure it worked, but it succeeded - see my update.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again and thanks for your great help! The information I want to scrape has changed slightlyafter all. As you similarly described, I want to pass the ID from the ```final_result``` dataframe into the URL. ```urls <- paste0("http://csla.history.ox.ac.uk/record.php?recid=", final_result$ID)```, e.g. http://csla.history.ox.ac.uk/record.php?recid=S01319. From each of these URLs, I want to scrape the Saint ID (e.g. 'S01319'), Name (e.g. 'Orientius, bishop of Auch, 5th c.'), Reported Death Not Before, Reported Death Not After, Gender, Type of Saint and present them in a dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the reference, *httr* (or at least *httr2*) knows how to post  `multipart/form-data`, makes dealing with those forms bit less scary:

```r
library(rvest)
library(httr2)
# multipart/form-data POST with httr2
request("http://csla.history.ox.ac.uk/results.php") %>%
  req_body_multipart(
    `form[item_998]` = "E",
    `form[item_89]`  = "Gaul",
    `form[item_999]` = "Or"
  ) %>%
  req_perform() %>%
  resp_body_string() %>% 
  # table html is broken, fix rows:
  gsub("</tr></tr>", "</tr><tr>", .) %>% 
  minimal_html() %>% 
  html_element("table") %>%
  html_table()

#> # A tibble: 1,210 × 2
#>    ID     Title                                                                 
#>    <chr>  <chr>                                                                 
#>  1 E02204 Calendar of the Church of Carthage (central North Africa) lists saint…
#>  2 E06072 The Life of *Hilary of Arles (Hilary/Hilarius, bishop of Arles, ob. 4…
#>  3 E06267 The Lives of the Abbots of Agaune *Hymnemodus, Ambrosius, Achivus, Tr…
#>  4 E06268 The Life of *Aglius (abbot of Rebais, ob. c. 650, $S02631) is written…
#>  5 E06269 The Life of *Amandus (missionary, monastic founder and bishop of Maas…
#>  6 E06270 The Martyrdom of *Andeolus the Subdeacon (martyr of Viviers, $S02362)…
#>  7 E06271 The Life of *Aper (hermit of Grenoble, $S02362) is written in Latin i…
#>  8 E06272 The Life of *Aper (bishop of Toul, ob. 6th c., $S02195) is written in…
#>  9 E06276 The Life of *Avitus (abbot of La Perche, ob. c. 525, $S01307) is writ…
#> 10 E06277 The Life of *Avitus (bishop of Vienne, ob. 519, $S01894) is written i…
#> # … with 1,200 more rows
```