# Scraping nested links

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to scrape http://csla.history.ox.ac.uk/search.php after applying a filter as follows

1. clicking on 'Saint'
2. selecting 'Gaul and Frankish kingdoms' under 'Region of Birth/Burial'
3. clicking on 'Apply Search'

I struggle as the URL does not get updated accordingly.

The source code with the `<option value="Gaul">Gaul and Frankish kingdoms</option>` looks as follows

```
<div class="section colm colm6" id="fl-page4-12">
<label for="item_12"class="field-label">Region of Birth/Burial</label>
<label class="field select">
<select id="text-nine" name="form[item_89]">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="East">'The East' (unspecified)</option>
<option value="West">'The West' (unspecified)</option>
<option value="Britain">Britain and Ireland</option>
<option value="Gaul">Gaul and Frankish kingdoms</option>
```

From the selected webpage, I would like to click on the IDs that are marked in blue (e.g. the first one is E06478).

From the then selected webpage (e.g. http://csla.history.ox.ac.uk/record.php?recid=E06478), I would like to click on the ID that is written in the table 'Related Saint Records' (e.g. the one here is S01319).

From the then selected webpage (e.g. http://csla.history.ox.ac.uk/record.php?recid=S01319), I would like to **scrape the Saint ID (e.g. 'S01319'), Name (e.g. 'Orientius, bishop of Auch, 5th c.'), Reported Death Not Before, Reported Death Not After, Gender, Type of Saint and present them in a dataframe.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I'm aware that [you have asked a similar question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72593129/scraping-webpage-when-filter-does-not-change-url), I'm going to continue the previously given solution

(The code at the beginning is copyied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72593561/10243060) solution, in this extension, we create new columns for the additional data, and scrape them again using `rvest`)

```r
library(httr)
library(rvest)

items <- c(998, 1, 18,89, 90, 2, 88, 20, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 13, 11, 999, 213, 214)
contents <- c('\nE\n', '\n\n', '\n\n', '\nGaul\n', rep('\n\n', 11), '\nOr\n',
              '\n\n', '\n\n')
s <- paste0("-----------------------------39565121210000504382566389445\n",
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"form[item_", items,
            ']\"\n', contents,
            collapse = '')
s <- paste0(s, '-----------------------------39565121210000504382566389445--')

type <- paste0('multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------',
               '39565121210000504382566389445')

res <- POST('http://csla.history.ox.ac.uk/results.php',
            body = charToRaw(s),
            content_type(type))

df <- res %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_elements(xpath = "//td[not(contains(@style, 'LightGray'))]") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  matrix(ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames(c('ID', 'Title')) %>%
  dplyr::as_tibble()


urls <- paste0("http://csla.history.ox.ac.uk/record.php?recid=", df$ID)

all_results <- list()

for(i in seq_along(urls)) {
  all_results[[i]] <- read_html(urls[i]) %>%
    html_elements("td") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    matrix(ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE) %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    setNames(c("ID", "Name", "Name_in_source", "Identity"))
}

final_result <- dplyr::bind_rows(all_results)

# continued solution ----------------------

additional_columns <- c("Name", "Number in BH", "Reported Death Not Before", "Reported Death Not After", "Gender", "Type of Saint")
final_result[, additional_columns] <- NA

for (i in seq_along(final_result$ID)) {
  web_page <- read_html(paste0("http://csla.history.ox.ac.uk/record.php?recid=", final_result$ID[[i]]))
  temp_res <- sapply(additional_columns, function(col) web_page %>%
             html_element(xpath = paste0("//div[contains(text(),'", col, "')]")) %>%
             html_children() %>% html_text())
  final_result[i, additional_columns] <- lapply(temp_res, function(x) ifelse(!length(x), NA, x))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jonathan! I would like to scrape the information for all Saints, i.e. I would like to remove ```[1:10]``` from ```urls <- paste0("http://csla.history.ox.ac.uk/record.php?recid=", df$ID)[1:10]```. When I do so, the ```final_result``` dataframe shows 3661 rows but only the first 20 rows contain information on Name, Reported Death not Before, Reported Death not After, Gender and Type of Saint. For example, for http://csla.history.ox.ac.uk/record.php?recid=S01178 information on Name, Reported Death, etc. is present but is not presented in the ```final_result``` dataframe.

Comment: Sorry, i've used only the first 10 values as test-values, i've updated the solution above with accounting for missing values, now it should work